# Xcode 6 - iOS8: Allow Master User To Update Information

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, content-management-system

I was wondering if anyone could point me to any useful tutorials on allowing a master user to update information for their app. I am looking into creating an application for a local restaurant and I want the owner to be able to update information like the soup of the day and such by themselves.

I have been looking into JSON and CMS for this, but I am unable to find any useful information regarding iOS 8 or xCode 6. If anyone could provide me with this information, or any other suggestions on how to achieve this I would be very grateful!

(I am using Swift not Objective-C)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a code issue, rather it is a development concept issue. You have many choices including making an API that is updated by the restaurant. The app then connects to the API and gets the recipes. If you feel you need to do this via the App make a special username that is allowed access to modify the menu. This can be accomplished via matching username exactly or via using a regex. It all really depends on the structure of your app platform.

Comment: I have this part down, but I cannot find any references for the new xcode on how to pull data from a URL, or anything to do with JSON files. Mind pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial Tutorial on working with JSON in Swift.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/ Class reference with swift calls. I have used NSURLConnection in the past well. aFNetworking is another option, but that forces you to make a bridge. I'm assuming you want swift clean code